# Python 3 os.rename will rename files, but not folders

Tags: python, rename

I am trying to rename all files and folders in a directory to replace '#' with '_'.  I wrote a quick Python 3.7 function to do this, and it successfully renamed all the files, but failed to rename any folder.  I am not getting any errors when I run this code.

```
import os

def replace(folder_path, old, new):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for name in files:
            if(old in name):
                file_path = os.path.join(path,name)
                print(file_path)
                new_path = os.path.join(path,name.replace(old,new))
                print(new_path)
                os.rename(file_path, new_path)


old = '#'
new = '_'
path = 'Y:\my_path_goes_here'

replace (path, old, new)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This code only iterates over the `files` item returned from `os.walk()`, therefore it never calls `os.rename()` on a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating **only** over the files, `subdirs` contains the list of folders.
More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I was missing something simple.